# CSS Keyframe Movements with Delays

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, animation, keyframe

I'm stumped with this animation. I have an element that I'm creating a path for movement (not including vendor prefixes in sample):

```
keyframes Path_1{
0%   {left:54%;top:66%;} 
50%  {left:54%;top:68%;} 
100% {left:54%;top:66%;}
}
```

This creates a simple path movement. 
Paths are supplied to some JS like so:

```
"path" : "54,66||54,68"
```

The JS loops through all coordinates passed in and automatically generates a path movement keyframe. It also handles adding the last coordinate pair to loop the animation.

I'm wondering if there is any way to supply specific speeds / delays to each point?

```
keyframes Path_1{
    0%   {left:54%;top:66%;}  <- 1s
    50%  {left:54%;top:68%;}  <- 5s
    100% {left:54%;top:66%;}  <- 10s
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide delays as extra parameters in the keyframe declaration. You basically get percentages within which you define which properties animate from what, to what during the fragment of animation overall time that the percentage defines.

However, there are ways of doing this. I've created a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mptfsaom/1/)

```
.animation {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
    animation: demo 5s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes demo {
    0% {
        width: 100px;
    }
    50% {
        width: 400px;
    }
    90% {
        width: 400px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

We can see that the animation is programmed to last 5s, but at one point a delay is achieved by keeping the animated properties static for *n*%. At 50%, the animation sticks at 400px and stays that way until 90% and the effect is a 2s pause. 40% of 5s = 2s.

Speed is also possible by adjusting the percentage and the overall time. The first section of the animation is slower than the second because the time spent to cover the same distance is just 10% of the overall time rather than 50%.

As usual, [CSS Tricks does a great run through](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) of what's available.

Now you just need to define this data in your json and interpret it in your javascript to build the correct keyframe anims, have fun with that!